# Is it possible to set up both audio chat and video chat using default embed?

Tags: opentok, tokbox

I'm trying to use tokbox to implement a video chat on the website page. I've decided to use "embed" for the sake of simplicity. Is it possible to choose for the clients whether to use both video and audio chat using default embed, or only audio chat? (Whenever I'm trying to start a chat without a camera it says that I don't have camera device)

Answer (score 0):

OpenTok Developer Advocate here.

The embed doesn't allow that granularity of control.  You'll want to use the OpenTok API to have the option of making audio only meetings.

You can learn more about how to do that at https://tokbox.com/developer/guides/audio-video/js/